# The named Parameters are not defined error

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, error-handling, parameters

Here is my code ,it is showing errors like The named parameter
'accentColor' isn't defined.Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'accentColor'.and the same with parameter 'brightness'.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    // import 'package:rangkings/config/config.dart';    
    // import '../config/config.dart';
    
    class ThemeModel {
      final lightMode = ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF3A52BC),
        accentColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        fontFamily: 'Manrope',
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColorDark: Colors.grey[800],
        primaryColorLight: Colors.white,
        secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.grey[600],
        shadowColor: Colors.grey[200],
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          color: Color(0xFF3A52BC),
          elevation: 0,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            // color: Colors.grey[900],
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey[900]),
          // textTheme: TextTheme(
          //   headline6: TextStyle(
          //     fontFamily: 'Manrope',
          //     fontSize: 18,
          //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          //     // color: Colors.grey[900],
          //     color: Colors.white,
          //   ),
          // ),
        ),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          subtitle1: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey[900]),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey[900]),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF3A52BC),
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[500],
        ),
      );
    
      final darkMode = ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
          primaryColor: Color(0xFF3A52BC),
          accentColor: Colors.white,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          fontFamily: 'Manrope',
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff303030),
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColorDark: Colors.grey[300],
          primaryColorLight: Colors.grey[800],
          secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.grey[400],
          shadowColor: Color(0xff282828),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            color: Colors.grey[900],
            elevation: 0,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            // textTheme: TextTheme(
            //   headline6: TextStyle(
            //     fontFamily: 'Manrope',
            //     fontSize: 18,
            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            //     color: Colors.white,
            //   ),
            // ),
          ),
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            subtitle1: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
            selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[500],
          ));
    }
```

Give an efficient solution for this errors,only those 4 errors are showing 2 accentColor one's and 2 brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `accentColor`, According to Flutter documentation

> The ThemeData accentColor, accentColorBrightness, accentIconTheme and accentTextTheme properties have been deprecated.
> The Material Design spec no longer specifies or uses an “accent” color for the Material components. The default values for component colors are derived from the overall theme’s color scheme. The ColorScheme’s secondary color is now typically used instead of accentColor and the onSecondary color is used when a contrasting color is needed.

Read more here https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties

Answer (score 0):

we don't have accent color and  brightness in ThemeData in current version of flutter anymore

Answer (score 0):

Both `accentColor` and `brightness` are deprecated, use `colorScheme.secondary` to replace `accentColor`, and `systemOverlayStyle` to replace `brightness`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> systemOverlayStyle

for brightness

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).